# after build app, connection error on android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions

my device on android marshmallow.
so I use get permission this method.

```
int currentApiVer = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Log.d(TAG, "currentApiVer = " + currentApiVer);

    if (currentApiVer >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.d(TAG, "currentApiVer ----------------------------");
        verifyPermissions(this);
    } //onCreate()

private static boolean verifyPermissions(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    Log.d(TAG, "verifyPermissions --------------------------------------");
    int writePerm = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int readPerm = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int camera_perm = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (writePerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            readPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            camera_perm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity, PERMISSIONS_REQ, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
        );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

my app is CCTV app. I use `WebRTC`
my problem when I first build my app.
show permission dialog. when I check permit permission.

success CCTV connect.

but I try again start built app.

fail CCTV connect.
clearly I already check permit permission.

perhaps, I think marshmallow permission problem.
in this situation. how I fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: You can use my library to handle runtime permissions easily:
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: what this library advantages?

Comment: less code and easy to use.

Comment: oh thanks. my app only success work , first app build.   this problem permission problem?..